# How to update capacitor to use android project to SDK v30

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

I am not sure how to update my capacitor Android project to target SDK v30.
Every time I do `rm -rf ./android && ionic capacitor copy android`
and edit the `build.gradle` and `variables.grade` to set

```
compileSdkVersion = 30
targetSdkVersion = 30
```

uploading the `apk` fails on the play store with

```
Your app currently targets API level 29 and must target at least API level 30 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 30.
```

I bet I only have to update capacitor somehow or run it with a flag, but just which one?

Comment: install latest capacitor: `npm install @capacitor/core`. then install latest android: `npm install @capacitor/android` then add android `npx cap add android`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you editing the correct build.gradle file? I believe the one to be edited is the build.gradle(Module:android.capacitor-app).

Or, open project properties from File/Project Structure. Then under variables, check your android (project). It should list the versions you have there. I believe these are editable last time I checked.